# Building a server for mobile based application

Tags: android, node.js, scala

> If I wish to build a server for a mobile based application should I
>   use Node js and Express or Scala and Play. I have read a couple of
>   online blogs and the more I read the more confused I become. I also
>   tried doing some micro benchmarking but dont find it of much use. 
>       According to what I read Scala applications have better CPU performance over Node js applications. Am I right in this ?
>    The factors I need to consider in this application are :
>   1. Performance
>   2. Scalability

Answer (score 2):

Performance and Scalability goals are relatively vague without more details. Both can be achieved with Scala (+Play) as well as Javascript (+Node).

Ask yourself this:

**Do you want Scala or Javascript in the backend?**

My more opinionated answer:
Do you really want a dynamically typed language like Javascript in the backend?

Full disclosure: Using Scala in production for a web+mobile app since 18 months now.

Answer (score 1):

There are as many options as there are languages. More, actually.

Your choice really depends on your specific needs. In many cases, it won't matter much which one you use. The performance bottleneck usually will come from network latency more than request processing/database access times. It may be best just to choose a server that is easiest for you to create/maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam. So talking about easy to maintain do you think a server developed in Node is easier to maintain than one in Scala ?

Comment: Programming in Scala will save you a lot of headache, type checking, compiler etc.